# Vectorized dot product much slower than for-loop version

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy

Ich wanted to optimize a critical part of my program where the most work is done. This work consists of computing many dot products.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
W = [np.random.rand(n_output, n_input) for _ in range(n_child)]
x = np.random.rand(n_input, batch_size)

for _ in range(n_times):
    for i in range(n_child):
        result[i] = np.dot(W[i],x)
    # work with result
```

I wanted to optimize this part by getting rid of the `for i in range(n_child)`-loop. So I did the following:

```
W = np.random.rand(n_child, n_output, n_input)
x = np.random.rand(n_input, batch_size)

for _ in range(n_times):
    results = np.dot(W,x)
    # work with result
```

However, this turned out to be much slower. Did I miss something? In the example below, my second approach is about 30 times slower. How is that possible?

Here is a fully working example:

```
import numpy as np
import time

n_child = 32
n_input = 1000
n_output = 20
batch_size = 64

W = np.random.rand(n_child, n_output, n_input)
x = np.random.rand(n_input, batch_size)

n_times = 1000

t0 = time.time()
for _ in range(n_times):
    np.dot(W,x)
t_a = time.time() - t0
print(t_a) # takes about 60 seconds on my machine

W = [np.random.rand(n_output, n_input) for _ in range(n_child)]

t0 = time.time()
for _ in range(n_times):
    for i in range(n_child):
        np.dot(W[i],x)
t_b = time.time() - t0
print(t_b) # takes about 3 seconds on my machine
```

Comment: Use `matmul` : `np.matmul(W,x)` or `W@x`?

Comment: @Divakar Hmm, it seems to be faster. But only slightly. But why is that the case?

Comment: Based on timings that I had done sometime earlier, `np.dot(W,x)` for 3D  `w` still loops through the first axis of `w`, while I think matmul doesn't.